# Getting image from ImageView instead of Drawable

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

**Please Note that I am a NEWBIE. Under Learning Process**

Right now what this code is doing? It is reading an image from drawable and then getting the text from it using google vision.

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.changing);
        TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

        if(!textRecognizer.isOperational()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();

            SparseArray<TextBlock> item = textRecognizer.detect(frame); //Yeh Frame Detect Kr rha he

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0 ; i<item.size();i++){
                TextBlock myitem = item.valueAt(i);
                sb.append(myitem.getValue());
                sb.append("\n");
            }
```

**NOTE:** R.drawable.changing is where "changing" is my image name. 
Now i want to replace the image with the image i uploaded on ImageView.

Any help would work.

Comment: How exactly do you set the image on the `ImageView`?

Comment: From Gallery. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6dWwoULFI8

Comment: You can get a `Bitmap` directly in `onActivityResult()`, without having to go through the `ImageView` (though you can still set it on the `ImageView`, too). Use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(intent.getData()))`, where `intent` is the `Intent` passed into `onActivityResult()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `Bitmap` from imageview like this

```
Drawable dr = ((ImageView) imView).getDrawable();
Bitmap bmp =  ((GlideBitmapDrawable)dr.getCurrent()).getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `ImageView.getDrawable()` to get the image from an ImageView. However, the drawable is not necessarily a BitmapDrawable (I think your `changing` drawable is).

To get an actual bitmap of the ImageView's drawable, you might have to look a bit further, on how to create a bitmap from an Android drawable. There are many answers to that in StackOverflow, so I will not repeat that here.

Basically, it's creating a Bitmap and a Canvas and then let the Drawable draw itself into the Bitmap, via the Canvas.

Comment: Tried to do it so many times but all i get is. Wrong 2nd Argument type. Found: 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable', required 'int'

Comment: You mean from BitmapFactory.decodeResource()? That's because the R.drawable.chaning is an int (a resource id), but ImageView.getDrawable() does not return the resource id, but an actual drawable. So you'll have to use a different method of BitmapFactory, or convert the drawable to a Bitmap as I described.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get image from drawable you can try this :

```
imageView.invalidate();
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

if you are getting image from resource like gallery:

```
if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
    {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

Another option for getting image is from camera:

```
if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
        {
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            final Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
```

where SELECT_FILE & REQUEST_CAMERA is just an integer:

```
int SELECT_FILE = 0;
int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
```